# Getting rid of an extra list in a list comprehension with nested loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have a pretty inelegant nested loop to clean up data from a csv - is there a better/more pythonic way to accomplish the below?

```
data = [[map(int, i.split(',')) for i in (item.strip() 
                                for item in line.rstrip('\n').split('\t'))][0] 
                                for line in open('input1.csv')]

output: [[8, -11, 1], [7, 7, -1], [12, -20, 1], [14, -3, -1], [12, 8, -1], [1, -12, 1], [15, 5, -1], [7, -10, 1], [10, 4, -1], [6, 2, 1], [8, 12, -1], [2, 20, -1], [1, -12, 1], [9, 8, -1], [3, 3, 1], [5, 6, 1], [1, 11, 1]]
```

In particular, in the second for loop I call index 0 of the list created by the last for loop (not sure that's the right terminology?).  Originally I had the below code, but this was generating a doubly nested list.  I stuck in the [0] to flatten the double nesting, but this seems like a pretty bad solution.

```
[[map(int, i.split(',')) for i in (item.strip() 
                         for item in line.rstrip('\n').split('\t'))] 
                         for line in open('input1.csv')]

output: [[[8, -11, 1]], [[7, 7, -1]], [[12, -20, 1]], [[14, -3, -1]], [[12, 8, -1]], [[1, -12, 1]], [[15, 5, -1]], [[7, -10, 1]], [[10, 4, -1]], [[6, 2, 1]], [[8, 12, -1]], [[2, 20, -1]], [[1, -12, 1]], [[9, 8, -1]], [[3, 3, 1]], [[5, 6, 1]], [[1, 11, 1]]]
```

Input data from csv below:

```
8,-11,1
7,7,-1
12,-20,1
14,-3,-1
12,8,-1
1,-12,1
15,5,-1
7,-10,1
10,4,-1
6,2,1
8,12,-1
2,20,-1
1,-12,1
9,8,-1
3,3,1
5,6,1
1,11,1
```

Comment: read the file with csv module!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data from input1.csv?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html) is the documentation for the csv module to get you started.  It looks like you have data sperated like `1,2,3\t4,5,6\t\n7,8,9`  Have you considered just replacing all the tabs with newlines?  It would be helpful to know why the data is formatted as it is

Comment: thanks all for the responses!  I added input data and am trying to csv module - great tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wim mentioned in his comment, this is not something you need to solve yourself!  I wrote your csv to a file called `eg.csv`, and ...

```
>>> import csv
>>> list(csv.reader(open('eg.csv')))
[['8', '-11', '1'], ['7', '7', '-1'], ['12', '-20', '1'], ['14', '-3', '-1'], ['12', '8', '-1'], ['1', '-12', '1'], ['15', '5', '-1'], ['7', '-10', '1'], ['10', '4', '-1'], ['6', '2', '1'], ['8', '12', '-1'], ['2', '20', '-1'], ['1', '-12', '1'], ['9', '8', '-1'], ['3', '3', '1'], ['5', '6', '1'], ['1', '11', '1']]
```

if you wanted them to be integers, you can do something like:

```
>>> [[int(col) for col in row] for row in csv.reader(open('eg.csv'))]
# or
>>> map(lambda x: map(int, x), csv.reader(open('eg.csv')))
# or
>>> [map(int, row) for row in csv.reader(open('eg.csv'))]
# to get
[[8, -11, 1], [7, 7, -1], [12, -20, 1], [14, -3, -1], [12, 8, -1], [1, -12, 1], [15, 5, -1], [7, -10, 1], [10, 4, -1], [6, 2, 1], [8, 12, -1], [2, 20, -1], [1, -12, 1], [9, 8, -1], [3, 3, 1], [5, 6, 1], [1, 11, 1]]
```

Unfortunately the builtin `csv` module does not attempt to deal with any type conversions.

Comment: follow up question - Any reason to do one of the two methods you showed for converting to integers instead of: `[map(int,i) for i in csv.reader(open('input1.csv'))]`?  Not sure if one is more/less elegant?

Comment: It will almost always be easier to read and maintain the list comprehensions, and list comprehensions are "more pythonic" (recommended by style guides).  If this was in another language (with currying), the map might look more elegant.  Nested loops are preferable in cases with much complexity.

I added a mixed option as an edit, which I consider the cleanest and most obvious.

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy squeeze to remove extra dimension on array or list

```
import numpy as np
np.squeeze([[map(int, i.split(',')) for i in (item.strip() 
                         for item in line.rstrip('\n').split('\t'))] 
                         for line in open('input1.csv')]).tolist()
```